# How to save data from a Properties object to a File + How to load the properties-formatted file to a Properties object in another Method?

Tags: java, properties

I want to save the data from the properties objecet `config` to the file `configFile` in the parameter like following:

```
@Override
public void saveConfig(Properties config, File configFile) {
    
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(configFile));
        os.writeObject(config);
        os.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

In the next method I want to load the properties-formatted `configFile` to a Properties object and return it:

```
@Override
public Properties loadConfig(File configFile) {
    
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    
    try(InputStream input = new FileInputStream(configFile)){
        prop.load(input);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return prop;
}
```

Somehow the JUnit test is showing me a NullPointerExeption (note: it is an exam)

```
if (!config.getProperty("testKey").equals("testValue"))
        fail("sample config data doesn't match read config data!");
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your `saveConfig` is using an `ObjectOutputStream` which stores the internal data of the Properties object in a binary encoding. However `loadConfig` tries to load the Properties as text file.You should probably use [`Properties.store`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.OutputStream,java.lang.String)) to write the Properties to the file. Also note that there are `store` and `load` overloads which have a `Writer` and `Reader` parameter and are not restricted to the ISO 8859-1 encoding.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet please?

Answer (score 1):

The following examples use the [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package which should be preferred to `java.io.File` due to its improved error handling. However, the code will look similarly for `java.io.File` as well.

#### Writing Properties

```java
@Override
public void saveConfig(Properties config, Path configFile) throws IOException {
    // Comments to be written at the beginning of the file;
    // `null` for no comments
    String comments = ...

    // try-with-resources to close writer as soon as writing finished
    // java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter​(...) uses UTF-8 by default
    try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(configFile)) {
        config.store(writer, comments);
    }
}
```

#### Reading Properties

```java
@Override
public Properties loadConfig(Path configFile) throws IOException {
    Properties config = new Properties();

    // try-with-resources to close reader as soon as reading finished
    // java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(...) uses UTF-8 by default
    try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(configFile)) {
        config.load(reader);
    }

    return config;
}
```